# React useState no se actualiza inmediatamente

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Verán, estoy creando un programa con react en el cual se muestra las banderas de varios países, pudiendo el el usuario filtrar que países se muestran según la región y por sus caracteres iniciales.

App.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import List from "./components/flags.js";
import Selection from "./components/formulario.js";
import Region from "./components/region.js";

const url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/";

const App = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [region, setRegion] = useState("all");
  const [limite, setLimite] = useState("");
  const [resultados, setResultados] = useState(0);

  const getCountries = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url + region);
    const data = await response.json();

    const largo = limite.length;
    let sub = "";

    if (largo > 0)
      for (let u = 0; u < data.length; u++) {
        sub = data[u].name.toLowerCase().slice(0, largo);
        if (sub != limite) {
          data.splice(u, 1);
          u--;
        }
      }

    setResultados(data.length);
    setCountries(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCountries("");
  }, []);

  function reseteo() {
    setCountries([]);
    getCountries();
  }

  const actualizar = (event) => {
    setLimite(event.target.value.toLowerCase());
    reseteo();
  };

  const restaurar = (event) => {
    setRegion(event.target.value);
    reseteo();
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Flags: {resultados}</h1>
      <Selection actualizar={actualizar} />
      <Region restaurar={restaurar} />
      <br />
      <br />
      <List naciones={countries} zona={region} />
    </main>
  );
};

export default App;
```

flags.js:

```
import React from "react";

const List = ({ naciones }) => {
  return (
    <section className="countries">
      {naciones.map((data) => (
        <article key={data.name}>
          <p>{data.name}</p>
          <p>{data.nativeName}</p>
          <picture>
            <img src={data.flag} alt={data.name} />
          </picture>
        </article>
      ))}
    </section>
  );
};

export default List;
```

formulario.js:

```
import React from "react";

const Selection = ({ actualizar }) => {
  return <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." onChange={actualizar} />;
};

export default Selection;
```

Por último, region.js:

```
import React from "react";

const Region = ({ restaurar }) => {
  return (
    <select onChange={restaurar}>
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="region/africa">Africa</option>
      <option value="region/americas">Americas</option>
      <option value="region/asia">Asia</option>
      <option value="region/europe">Europe</option>
      <option value="region/oceania">Oceania</option>
    </select>
  );
};

export default Region;
```

La historia es que si modifico los elementos de formulario de formulario.js y region.js, modificará los valores de las variables "limite" y "region", pero debido a que las funciones setLimite() y setRegion() funcionan de forma asincrona, al ejecutarse la función getCountries tendrá en cuenta el valor anterior, causando errores.

Por ejemplo, si digo que quiero mostrar solo los países de Europa, tengo, tras elegir Europa en la etiqueta "select", que escoger otro valor para que me muestre los países europeos.

Algo que me sugirieron es usar useEffect() para modificar las variables, pero al hacerlo me salen errores debido a que necesita que las funciones reseteo() y actualizar() sean extensiones de React.

Comment: En tu <App> porque llamas la funcion `getCountries("");` en `useEffect()` con un argumento String vacio? si tu declaracion de la misma no tiene argumentos?

Comment: @RicardoSanchez El código da error y no carga la lista de banderas si no lo incluyo, aunque de todas formas no entiendo bien como va ese useEffect().